# Server setup for 1000 concurrent users

Tags: php, performance, testing, joomla, load

I'm building an online test/quiz website on Joomla! 3 which uses PHP + MySQLi on Apache (or nginx) at DigitalOcean. The quiz will run for 6 hours a day during working hours for a month catering to about 150,000 users in total.

My client says there will be 1000-1200 users at a given time taking the quiz. I'm wondering what kind of server setup would be necessary in terms of CPU and RAM or would there be other factors?

Currently there's a plan for $320 with 24GB Memory & 16 Dedicated vCPU at DigitalOcean. Will this server configuration do?

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault, not StackOverflow. https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Probably multiple load balanced servers to provide resilience if it's that important

Answer (score 3):

You will need at least the following:

- A **dedicated** server with 20+ cores, 64+ GB of RAM, and an SSD drive
- Substantial database optimization in the my.cnf file (mostly for InnoDB)
- Core/Extension optimization

You will also need to test the performance your website using "ab" - you can take a look at how this can be done [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/comparing-the-performance-of-joomla-3-8-1-to-joomla-3-7-5).

I think the most important thing to do is to ensure that you have no unoptimized queries in the quiz extension that you're using, because, in our experience, all these Joomla quiz extensions are extremely unoptimized.